# Download file using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to download file from the SharePoint portal.

I was able to login successfully and open the file, but unable to download the file via script. Could you please advise. Thanks.

```
$username= user_name
$password = password
$url = "https://share.mycompany.com/"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)


Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000

$ie.Document.getElementByID("Ecom_User_ID").value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementByID("Ecom_Password").value = $password
$ie.document.getElementById("loginBtn").click()

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10000
$source = "https://share.mycompany.com/sites/department/SomeExcelFile.xlsx"

$ie.navigate($source)
$obj = new-object -com WScript.Shell
$obj.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
$obj.SendKeys('s')
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use SharePoint 2013 or later I would suggest to use the [SharePoint Pnp PowerShell Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) for this any many other operations in SharePoint.

In this case the Get-pnpfile command

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps

Example:

```
Get-PnPFile -Url /sites/project/_catalogs/themes/15/company.spcolor -Path c:\temp -FileName company.spcolor -AsFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
Function Download-File([string]$FileUrl,[string]$DownloadPath)
 {    
    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FileUrl)
    $downloadFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($DownloadPath,$fileName)
    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $client.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("lee", "password", "domain")    
    $client.DownloadFile($FileUrl, $downloadFilePath)
    $client.Dispose()
}

Download-File -FileUrl http://sp:12001/MyDoc/test2.docx -DownloadPath "C:\Lee\PSDownLoad"
```

Comment: Hi Lee, I got the below error message. Please advice.  "Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Answer (score 0):

On SharePoint 2010 you can either use the .Net methods as referenced by Lee_MSFT but I find it easier to download files from SharePoint via [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) especially if you are running in the context of an account with access to the file.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://some.site.org/sites/knowledge/documents/myfile.zip' `
                  -UseDefaultCredentials `
                  -OutFile c:\temp\myfile.zip
```